# Dynamically add a list of child components in React

Tags: reactjs

I tried to add a list of a child in react, but I don't know why when I put function to add a child in a loop, it just adds the last element of the list. , is my logic missing something?

my state

```
 const [hobbyFields, setHobbyFields] = useState([
    { id: uuidv4(), hobbyName: "" },
  ]);
```

function for hanle text in field changing

```
 const onHobbyFieldChange = (id, event) => {
    const newHobbyFields = hobbyFields.map((hobbyField) => {
      if (hobbyField.id === id) {
        hobbyField.hobbyName = event.target.value;
      }
      return hobbyField;
    });
    setHobbyFields(newHobbyFields);
  };
```

function for add list of child

```
const onHobbySelectedCallback = (listHobby) =>{
    if(listHobby){
      listHobby.forEach(hobby =>{
        handleAddFields(hobby)
      })
    }
  }
const handleAddFields = (hobbyName) => {
    setHobbyFields([...hobbyFields, { id: uuidv4(), hobbyName }]);
  };
```

and where I use it

```
<Form>
          {hobbyFields.map((hobbyField) => (
            <Form.Group
              className="d-flex justify-content-start mt-3"
              key={hobbyField.id}
            >
              <Form.Control
                type="text"
                value={hobbyField.hobbyName}
                onChange={(event) => onHobbyFieldChange(hobbyField.id, event)}
              />
              <Button variant="info" onClick={() =>handleAddFields("")}>
                Add
              </Button>
              <Button
                variant="danger"
                onClick={() => handleRemoveFields(hobbyField.id)}
              >
                Remove
              </Button>
            </Form.Group>
          ))}
        </Form>
```

have a nice day, everyone!

Comment: Your code seems to work for me. When I click the add-button a new element is added to the list. What is your expected behavior? Do you want new elements to appear below the add-button you just pressed?

Comment: i fixed . my mean is user get a list hobby from server, user can choose a list hobby from that, then i loop the list and add into new field. But thanks so much